# How to share with "Anyone with the link" Rails 3 / gem 'google_drive'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-drive-api

Using Rails 3.2.13 & gem 'google_drive'

In my controller:

```
session = GoogleDrive.login("*@gmail.com", "***")    
session.create_spreadsheet("My new sheet")
ws = session.spreadsheet_by_title('My new sheet').worksheets[0]
ws[2, 1] = "foi3o"
ws[2, 2] = "bar321643"
ws.save()
```

How to set sharing to "Anyone with the link"? Right now it is creating a private sheet only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spreadsheet.acl.push({:scope_type => "default", :with_key => true, :role => "writer"})`

More info in gem's source:
https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/lib/google_drive/acl.rb